# I am having trouble installing an internal wifi card.

Tags: wireless

I downloaded ubuntu version 16.04 today and I'm having trouble installing my internal wifi card. It is Linksys Wireless-G 2.4ghz PCI Adapter. Model No.: WMP54GS.

I have spent several hours online trying to look how to get wifi I would appreciate any help

Comment: Please edit your question to add the result of this terminal command: `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A2` There are several versions of this device, each with different chipsets.

Comment: it says: 07:04.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4318 [AirForce One 54g] 802.11g Wireless LAN Controller [14e4:4318] (rev 02)
 Subsystem: Linksys WMP54GS v1.1 802.11g Wireless-G PCI Adapter with SpeedBooster [1737:0042]
 Kernel driver in use: b43-pci-bridge

Comment: Did you test the `Additional Drivers` steps provided in the answer?

Comment: Yes when I get to Additional Drivers in Software & Updates all I get is Unknown:Unknown 
This device is not working.
Using Processor microcode firmware for Intel CPUs from intel-microcode (proprierty)
Do not use the device

Comment: @KevinArriaga Please don't add "Solved" to the title.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Installing Broadcom Wireless Drivers](http://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers)

Answer (score 1):

With a temporary internet connection by ethernet, tethered or whatever means possible, open a terminal and do:

```
sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer
```

Reboot.

Answer (score 0):

A number of users have reported success by using the Ubuntu's `Additional Drivers`.

You can use this by going to:

**Additional Drivers**

> System Settings -> Software & Updates -> Additional Drivers -> [Select
>   the Best Match and Apply Changes]

Alternatively you could use the distributed Windows drivers via Ubuntu's `ndiswrapper`.

The steps for this is:

**Using Windows Drivers via ndiswrapper**

Install the ndiswrapper modules:

```
$ sudo apt-get install ndiswrapper-dkms ndisgtk ndiswrapper-common
$ sudo apt-get install  ndiswrapper-source ndiswrapper-utils-1.9
```

Activate the ndiswrapper:

```
$ sudo modprobe ndiswrapper
```

Load the driver into the ndiswrapper:
Navigate to where you saved the driver (look at grab latest drivers in the section below):

```
$ sudo ndiswrapper -i [driver]  # (named something similar to "bcmwlhigh5.ini" 
  # (Add the ndiswrapper modules to the boot configuration) 
$ sudo ndiswrapper -m
```

More details can be found at: http://faq.apollo3.com/ljames/ubuntu/networksupport/

Comment: *Additional Drivers* only installs Broadcom wireless drivers. Do you think his device is a Broadcom?

Comment: @chili555 I don't know if his device is broadcom.  Also I didn't know that Broadcom was the only third party supplier of drivers to the `Additional Drivers` facility.  I'm just familiar with the success of it for various hardware support.  In case it doesn't work for his instance, I added an alternative that has always worked for me using drivers distributed by the manufacturer for windows.  By the way, searching the web I find: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1629701&p=10161003#post10161003

Comment: I recommend that you find out the device *first* and then propose a solution. Did you also find this on a search? https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HardwareSupportComponentsWirelessNetworkCardsLinksys There are *six* versions listed with all different chipsets.

Comment: The steps that I provided has always worked with hardware that I have encountered.  `Additional Drivers` only having support for Broadcom is new information for me.  I appreciate this information.  Can you link me a reference to this.  It will help me in my research for why it works.  As far as the current user having problems, it has probably worked for him, otherwise he might have mentioned that the `Additional Drivers` screen is blank, or loads drivers that doesn't work.  I was going to post the alternative which I just updated, if the `Additional Drivers` option failed.